Imagemagick does not install legacy tools despite me asking to
Imagemagick does not install the legacy tools (and especially convert) when I install it, and installing legacy tools is enabled
Is this a software bug or am just I doing something wrong?

magick (or magick.exe I'd assume) is the command now, for a few versions.

@JayCravens the program i'm using requires imagemagick's legacy convert, any way i can fix this?

You could try renaming it to convert.exe (it is essentially the same program) but that will only work if it's a standalone .exe.  Won't hurt to try.  If not, the program requiring it must update the name.  You could also roll back by a few versions, before it was changed.

For older versions you can look on SourceForge

solved the problem by downloading an older version off an archive.org snapshot of imagemagick.org
